# How can I save the state of my program and then load it?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, imageicon

I'm trying to save and reload the state of my Swing program, which in this case is a Minesweeper game. My code for the board is below.

```
package mines;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    public static void main (String[] args)  {}
    private final int NUM_IMAGES = 13;
    private final int CELL_SIZE = 15;

    private final int COVER_FOR_CELL = 10;
    private final int MARK_FOR_CELL = 10;
    private final int EMPTY_CELL = 0;
    private final int MINE_CELL = 9;
    private final int COVERED_MINE_CELL = MINE_CELL + COVER_FOR_CELL;
    private final int MARKED_MINE_CELL = COVERED_MINE_CELL + MARK_FOR_CELL;

    private final int DRAW_MINE = 9;
    private final int DRAW_COVER = 10;
    private final int DRAW_MARK = 11;
    private final int DRAW_WRONG_MARK = 12;

    private int[] field;
    private boolean inGame;
    private int mines_left;
    private Image[] img;
    private int mines = 40;
    private int rows = 16;
    private int cols = 16;
    private int all_cells;
    private JLabel statusbar;

    public Board(JLabel statusbar) {

        this.statusbar = statusbar;

        img = new Image[NUM_IMAGES];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++) {
            img[i] =
                (new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource((i)
                    + ".png"))).getImage();
        }

        setDoubleBuffered(true);

        addMouseListener(new MinesAdapter());

        newGame();
    }


    public void newGame() {

        Random random;
        int current_col;

        int i = 0;
        int position = 0;
        int cell = 0;

        random = new Random();
        inGame = true;
    mines_left = mines;

    all_cells = rows * cols;
    field = new int[all_cells];

    for (i = 0; i < all_cells; i++)
        field[i] = COVER_FOR_CELL;

    statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));


    i = 0;
    while (i < mines) {

        position = (int) (all_cells * random.nextDouble());

        if ((position < all_cells) &&
            (field[position] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)) {


            current_col = position % cols;
            field[position] = COVERED_MINE_CELL;
            i++;

            if (current_col > 0) { 
                cell = position - 1 - cols;
                if (cell >= 0)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
                cell = position - 1;
                if (cell >= 0)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;

                cell = position + cols - 1;
                if (cell < all_cells)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
            }

            cell = position - cols;
            if (cell >= 0)
                if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                    field[cell] += 1;
            cell = position + cols;
            if (cell < all_cells)
                if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                    field[cell] += 1;

            if (current_col < (cols - 1)) {
                cell = position - cols + 1;
                if (cell >= 0)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
                cell = position + cols + 1;
                if (cell < all_cells)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
                cell = position + 1;
                if (cell < all_cells)
                    if (field[cell] != COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                        field[cell] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


public void find_empty_cells(int j) {

    int current_col = j % cols;
    int cell;

    if (current_col > 0) { 
        cell = j - cols - 1;
        if (cell >= 0)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

        cell = j - 1;
        if (cell >= 0)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

        cell = j + cols - 1;
        if (cell < all_cells)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }
    }

      cell = j - cols;
    if (cell >= 0)
        if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
            field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
            if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                find_empty_cells(cell);
        }

       cell = j + cols;
       if (cell < all_cells)
        if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
            field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
            if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                find_empty_cells(cell);
           }

          if (current_col < (cols - 1)) {
           cell = j - cols + 1;
             if (cell >= 0)
               if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

           cell = j + cols + 1;
            if (cell < all_cells)
               if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
            }

          cell = j + 1;
           if (cell < all_cells)
            if (field[cell] > MINE_CELL) {
                field[cell] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                if (field[cell] == EMPTY_CELL)
                    find_empty_cells(cell);
               }
        }

       }

      public void paint(Graphics g) {

       int cell = 0;
        int uncover = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {

            cell = field[(i * cols) + j];

            if (inGame && cell == MINE_CELL)
                inGame = false;

            if (!inGame) {
                if (cell == COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                    cell = DRAW_MINE;
                } else if (cell == MARKED_MINE_CELL) {
                    cell = DRAW_MARK;
                } else if (cell > COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                    cell = DRAW_WRONG_MARK;
                } else if (cell > MINE_CELL) {
                    cell = DRAW_COVER;
                }


            } else {
                if (cell > COVERED_MINE_CELL)
                    cell = DRAW_MARK;
                else if (cell > MINE_CELL) {
                    cell = DRAW_COVER;
                    uncover++;
                }
            }

            g.drawImage(img[cell], (j * CELL_SIZE),
                (i * CELL_SIZE), this);
        }
       }


      if (uncover == 0 && inGame) {
        inGame = false;
        statusbar.setText("Game won");
      } else if (!inGame)
        statusbar.setText("Game lost");
       }




     class MinesAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
       public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();

        int cCol = x / CELL_SIZE;
        int cRow = y / CELL_SIZE;

        boolean rep = false;


          if (!inGame) {
            newGame();
            repaint();
          }


         if ((x < cols * CELL_SIZE) && (y < rows * CELL_SIZE)) {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {

                if (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] > MINE_CELL) {
                    rep = true;

                    if (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] <= COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                        if (mines_left > 0) {
                            field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] += MARK_FOR_CELL;
                            mines_left--;
                            statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));
                        } else
                            statusbar.setText("No marks left");
                    } else {

                        field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] -= MARK_FOR_CELL;
                        mines_left++;
                        statusbar.setText(Integer.toString(mines_left));
                    }
                }

            } else {

                if (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] > COVERED_MINE_CELL) {
                    return;
                }

                if ((field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] > MINE_CELL) &&
                    (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] < MARKED_MINE_CELL)) {

                    field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] -= COVER_FOR_CELL;
                    rep = true;

                    if (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] == MINE_CELL)
                        inGame = false;
                    if (field[(cRow * cols) + cCol] == EMPTY_CELL)
                        find_empty_cells((cRow * cols) + cCol);
                }
            }

            if (rep)
                repaint();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try serialization for persisting java object

Comment: you can save the state of each cell and retrieve it later. or as @upog    said serialize the object and store it in database.

Answer (score 7):

There are any number of possible choices...

### You could

Use the `Properties` API, which provides save and load functionality.

The API works like a `Map`, allowing you to store key/value pairs, which you can save and load as required.

The API only allows you to store `String` values, so you would need to convert non-String values manually.

Just remember to save them as the API does not automatically persist the changes

Take a look at [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) for more details.

### You could

Roll you own XML file or use something like [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) which allows you to bind properties of object and export/import them to/from XML

This approach would be more flexible then using `Properties`, but introduces a level of complexity

### You Could

Use the [`Preferences`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) API, which allows you to store `String` and primitive values, with out the need to perform any type of converstion.

The `Preferences` API also automatically loads and stores it's content, but it will do so where it wants to, so you lose control over where the content is stored.

### You Could

Use a stand alone/single user database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) for example.  It's a little more complicated but does take care of the basic storage requirements.

It would also require additional time to update should you change your requirements, over something like using `Properties` or `Preferences` and might be a little overkill if all you are storing is the cell data...IMHO

### You Could

Try using object serialization, but the API was never meant for the long term storage of object states and carries its own bag of problems and I would personally avoid it, but that's me.

Answer (score 1):

In a Java app., there are a great variety of ways to go about serializing app. data.

- For applets there are cookies.
- For apps. launched using JWS, the `PersistenceService`
- Any app. might use the `Preferences` API.

All those forms of serialization are meant for stuff that can be encoded into a String based name and value.

- A `Properties` file is also good for name/value type info.
- For more complex data I would create a bean and use `XMLEncoder`/`XMLDecoder`.
- A Zip file is good for serializing data that might be in many different forms (e.g. part XML, part Properties, some screenshot images..).

If using the properties, XML or Zip archive, a good place to save the info. is a sub-directory of `user.home`.  It is reproducible and the app. should have read/write permissions.