# Java Swing JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

In my game im currently working on a basic main menu and im looking for a few things.

1. Currently the only way to see which Jslider is which is by hovering over it.. any suggestions?
2. When i change the JSlider brightness or the JSlider audio it doesnt actualy update until i switch tabs and return.
3. When i close the game and reopen it the settings return to default. how to create a variable to preserve settings?

all code is here https://github.com/FeatheredOrcian/Kingdomcraft.git

if you would rather just see the class that the code is partaining to https://github.com/FeatheredOrcian/Kingdomcraft/blob/master/Kingdomcraft/src/com/pointlight/kingdomcraft/render/Render.java

thx

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow this is a Q&A site, your question is too vague, you have to explain your issue in a detailed manner: what is happening, what do you want to happen and show the relevant code here, linking the code is unadvised. But most importantly you must only post the relevant code, preferably a [MCTR example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We are not here to fix or improve your project, that is your job, but If you have and specific question or issue we may be able to help you out.

Comment: well... i had 3 questions and I wasn't specifically asking for you to "fix" it for me. I posted the link to the project so that you could run it, tell me whats wrong, and we would go threw the edjicational process. Yes I know where I am and what StackOverflow is that was implied when I posted here. Keep in mind im 14.

Comment: 1- add a JLabel or use a TitledBorder. 2- you should have a ChangeListener to monitor changes. 3- there are a number of questions on SO which should help, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'd suggest you add a JLabel next to your slider
2. You need to update the setToolTipText in your statechangelistener. Whenever the state changes, you want you need to let your slider know that it's tooltiptext has changed.
3. You want to use something like Preferences. [Preferences API Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html)

*As MadProgrammer mentioned in the comments. Avoid using setBounds, setSize or setLocation. Please review [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The only reason I kept them in the below code is so you could see how to implement the suggestions to the 3 questions you asked.

Below is an example of the code changes that I mentioned above. Good luck!

```
        settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                remove(createWorld);
                remove(addServer);
                repaint();

                // Get stored preferences and specific default values if they
                // do not exist
                final Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(Render.class);
              soundLevel = prefs.getInt("SOUND_LEVEL", 50);
              lightLevel = prefs.getInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", 50);

              // Add sound label
                JLabel soundLabel = new JLabel("Sound: ");
                soundLabel.setBounds(170, 110, 150, 35);
                soundLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

                add(soundLabel);
                add(sound);
                sound.setBounds(210, 110, 150, 35);
                sound.setMinimum(0);
                sound.setMaximum(100);
                sound.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                sound.setValue(soundLevel);
                sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");
                sound.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                        soundLevel = sound.getValue();

                        // Update tooltip value
                    sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");

                    // Save sound value in pref
                 prefs.putInt("SOUND_LEVEL", soundLevel);
                    }
                });

                // Add light label
            JLabel lightLabel = new JLabel("Light: ");
            lightLabel.setBounds(370, 110, 150, 35);
            lightLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

            add(lightLabel);
                add(light);
                light.setBounds(405, 110, 150, 35);
                light.setMinimum(0);
                light.setMaximum(100);
                light.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                light.setValue(lightLevel);
            light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");

                light.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                        lightLevel = light.getValue();

                        // Update tooltip value
                    light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");

                    // Save light value in pref
                    prefs.putInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", lightLevel);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Don't use or suggest using setBounds, setSize or setLocation (or null layouts by extension). There is no excuse to use these in moderne GUIs. They increase the work load by a factor of 10 and immediately decrease the portability of your application to 0

Comment: @MadProgrammer agreed -- I only used it because his previous code had it and providing a different solution that he could plug and play would be very involved. -- Updated recommended solution with a note on setBounds, setSize, and setLocation.

Comment: how would i avoid that then\

Comment: i just wanna say that ive been learning java for 1 1/2 years and this is the stuff i like to learn

Comment: @implementsFeatheredOrcian Read the tutorial on Layout Managers.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: well im looking at the oracle doc and i get whats they are showing but this all seam pretty much... well.. perfectly organized. how would i get it so that it creates another jbutton parallel to an already existent jbutton.

Comment: sorry if i ask a question and your like god just look at the link

Comment: how crucial is it if i leave it like this because i could wip up a quick fps counter

Comment: maybe it would be more beneficial for me if i just worry about that once i get the terrain generation completed. im doing voxels and im thinking about perlin noise so im going to wip up a new thread thx;

Comment: @implementsFeatheredOrcian The use of layout managers are crucial for any form based GUI, as it takes care of the inconsistencies of font rending between different platforms. You can argue that it's only ever going to run on a ingle platform, but perfect practice makes perfect. Build good habits now, so they are simply second nature when it matters (which is all the time)