# How to "save" my program?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Hi guys I'm currently working on a kind of "dungeon crawler" game and i need some help with saving my program. I would like for my jFrame to save(all of my entered text)so that when i close the program and open it back up from my Desktop it will have my entered text and everything i have changed still in the program. I'm confused as to how to save and am hoping for some help. Thanks ahead of time for all of your time, anwsers, links, examples, and advice. To be clear i am new to this and only have been coding for about 5 days now and i still use the Netbeans jFrame "Design" feature to generate most of the code for me.  Below I've posted the code for my second Jframe. Feel free to copy and paste this code in your netbeans IDE. Thanks :).

NOTE: in case needing the names for my other Jframes.
"Character" is my second jFrame
"MainClass" is my java app
"MainGamePanel" is my third JFrame

NOTE:some buttons may not work because this is not all of my jFrames

```
package ddsheet; //This is the code for my jFrame named Character

import java.nio.file.Files;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Character extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Character() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        nameValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        strValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        int1Value = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dexValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        vitValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hpValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        mpValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        stamValue = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jProgressBar1 = new javax.swing.JProgressBar();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Class = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Character"));

        jLabel1.setText("Name:");

        jLabel2.setText("Level:");

        jLabel3.setText("Gold:");

        jLabel4.setText("Str:");

        jLabel5.setText("Int:");

        jLabel6.setText("Dex:");

        jLabel7.setText("Vit:");

        jLabel8.setText("Hp:");

        jLabel9.setText("Mp");

        jLabel10.setText("Stam:");

        jButton1.setText("Main Menu");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jLabel11.setText("Inventory");

        nameValue.setText("Hiroshema");

        jLabel13.setText("1");

        jLabel14.setText("550");

        strValue.setText("0");

        int1Value.setText("0");

        dexValue.setText("0");

        vitValue.setText("0");

        hpValue.setText("0");

        mpValue.setText("0");

        stamValue.setText("0");

        jLabel12.setText("EXP:");

        Class.setText("Class");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                                        .addGap(35, 35, 35))
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                .addComponent(nameValue))
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                        .addComponent(int1Value, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                                                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 11, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(dexValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                        .addComponent(strValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(vitValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 49, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(hpValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(mpValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                                                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                                                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel14))
                                                                                                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                                                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel13)))
                                                                                                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                                                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                                                                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                .addComponent(stamValue, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                                                                                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 90, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 233, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel11))
                                                                                                                                        .addGap(97, 97, 97))
                                                                                                                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(Class)
                                                                                                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel12)
                                                                                                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                                                                                .addContainerGap())))
                );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
                jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                .addComponent(jProgressBar1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addComponent(jLabel12))
                                                .addGap(26, 26, 26))
                                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(Class)
                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)))
                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                                .addComponent(nameValue)
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel11))
                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel13))
                                                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel14))
                                                                                                .addGap(41, 41, 41)
                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                                                                                        .addComponent(strValue))
                                                                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                                                                                                .addComponent(int1Value))
                                                                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                                                                                                        .addComponent(dexValue))
                                                                                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                                                                                                                .addComponent(vitValue))
                                                                                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(hpValue))
                                                                                                                                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                                                                                                                                                .addComponent(mpValue))
                                                                                                                                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                                                                                                                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(stamValue))
                                                                                                                                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                                                                                                                                                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 283, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                                                                                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                );

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        jMenuItem1.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_E, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem1.setText("Exit");
        jMenuItem1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S, java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        jMenuItem2.setText("Save");
        jMenuItem2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())
                );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        System.exit(0);
    }                                          

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        this.dispose();
        new MainGamePanel().setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    }                                          

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Character.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Character.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Character.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Character.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Character().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public static javax.swing.JLabel Class;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel dexValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel hpValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel int1Value;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JProgressBar jProgressBar1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel mpValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel nameValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel stamValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel strValue;
    public static javax.swing.JLabel vitValue;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: If its just text, save it out to a text file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/. If its objects, serialize: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: @NicolásCarlo - Its an answer :P

Comment: Don't think about saving a frame. Think about saving your game state. Choose an easy to parse format like JSON or XML for example.

Comment: [Some additional ideas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052)

Comment: So about saving the game state. how do i use this JSON or XML?

Comment: Start by creating a class containing the game state. For example, if you were to save the state of a chess game, this ChessGameState class would contain a list of pieces, each piece having a kind (king, tower, etc.), a color (black, white), and a coordinate on the chess board. It would also contain the player (white or black) who will play the next move. Then use a JSON or XML serializer to write an instance of this ChessGameState class.

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet for your responses and thanks Nicolas Carlo, MadProgrammer for the links to information i need. I think ill be able to do it now that i have good resources to refer to. ^o^ Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

another idea is create a separate class containing all the information you need to save. 
And use the class as an object in your main class and then save the object like this.

Look into serializing a class (this is called serialization).

```
public class GameState implements Serializable{
...//game settings and states stored here
}

//inside the main running class
my_settings = GameState();
...
// write object
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path..);
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
out.writeObject( my_settings );
out.close();
fos.close();

//read object
fis = new FileInputStream(path..);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
my_settings = (GameState) ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

xml mabye?

I think you may be able to use a `FileOutputStream` and `PrintWriter` to create an xml file with data nodes keeping data of the state of everything in the game. to read it back, you might want to use Simple API for XML (SAX).   
Just an idea.