# Saving an object file when the frame is closed

Tags: java, swing, serialization, io

So what im trying to do is have the program save the file when the user clicks the quit button, so that the next time i run it, all the users entered the first time are still there. Every time i rerun the program, the file is empty and it is as if the first run never happened. What do i need to do to get the file to save?

So this is what i have now, but it is only saving the input from the very first run and never adds new users when i run it. Did i put something in the wrong place or forget anything?

```
public class Admin extends JFrame  implements ActionListener{

static ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
static FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fis;
static ObjectOutputStream oos;
ObjectInputStream ois;
JTextField realname = new JTextField("", 20);
JTextField username = new JTextField("", 20);
JTextField password = new JTextField("", 20);
JTextField repassword = new JTextField("", 20);
JLabel rnlabel = new JLabel("Real Name");
JLabel unlabel = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel pwlabel = new JLabel("Password");
JLabel rpwlabel = new JLabel("Rewrite Password");
String name;
String uname;
StringBuilder S = new StringBuilder("Registered Users\n");



//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException,FileNotFoundException,IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
try{
    Admin admin = new Admin();
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e){ 
    System.err.println(" A ClassNotFoundException error was found in main."); 
    e.printStackTrace();
    }       
//catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){ System.err.println("SHA-1 algorithm not available"); System.exit(0);}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
    System.err.println(" A FileNotFoundException error was found in main.");
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println(" A IOException error was found in main.");
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Data members for the controller. 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();

JButton quitButton = new JButton("Quit");

JPanel newCard = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JButton submitButton = new JButton("Submit");
JPanel buttonPanel1 = new JPanel( new GridLayout(6, 1));
JTextArea data = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane userPane = new JScrollPane( data );

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public Admin() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException {
    setBounds(200, 200, 800, 200);
    initComponents();
    submitButton.addActionListener(this);
    quitButton.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);


}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e) {

    try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
        users = (ArrayList<User>) is.readObject();
        updateList();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == submitButton){
        name = realname.getText();
        uname = username.getText();
        getPassword();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(users.get(i).toString());
        }
        updateList();
    }

    if (source == quitButton) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
            os.writeObject(users);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------  
protected void updateList() {
    for (User object : users) {
        S.append(object + "\n");
    }
    String text = S.toString();
    data.setText(text);
}


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
private void getPassword() {

    String pw = password.getText().toString();
    String pword_check = repassword.getText().toString();
    if (pw.equals(pword_check)){
        users.add(new User(name, uname, pw));
        realname.setText("");
        username.setText("");
        password.setText("");
        repassword.setText("");
    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, 
                "Passwords do not match. Re-enter both of them.");
        password.setText("");
        repassword.setText("");
    }
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void initComponents(){
    //-- The New User Screen -----------------------------------------------
    JPanel rname = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 3));
    rname.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2));
    rname.add(realname);
    rname.add(rnlabel);

    JPanel uname = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 3));
    uname.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2));
    uname.add(username);
    uname.add(unlabel);

    JPanel npword = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 3));
    npword.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2));
    npword.add(password);
    npword.add(pwlabel);

    JPanel nrpword = new JPanel( new GridLayout(1, 3));
    nrpword.setLayout( new GridLayout(1, 2));
    nrpword.add(repassword);
    nrpword.add(rpwlabel);

    buttonPanel1.add(rname, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.add(uname, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.add(npword, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.add(nrpword, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.add(submitButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.add(quitButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 10));
    newCard.add(buttonPanel1);
    userPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 50));
    newCard.add(userPane, "East");


    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    tp.addTab( "New User", newCard);
    super.setTitle("Login System");
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.add(tp, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
}

}
```

Comment: You're reading the object when you process the quitButton?

Answer (score 1):

There's an interface called [`WindowListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) that you should implement in your class. It allows you to execute code on window open close etc..

Comment: *So what im trying to do is have the program save the file when the user clicks the quit button*. Can you help to solve this issue rather than providing another handler.

Comment: @Braj I up-voted your comment, then I looked again at the title of *"Saving an object file **when the frame is closed**"* and that puts the 'button' in a different context.  If referring to the little `x` button I see on a desktop app. in Windows, I'd expect it to close.  If a Java app. needs to do things on app. close, a `WindowListener` is a good way to detect that 'closing' state.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the contents of the file on `quitButton`

```
if (source == quitButton) {
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("userfile.txt");
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ev) {
        ev.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

instead of writing...

You could try something more like...

```
if (source == quitButton) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
        os.writeObject(users);
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

instead...

To read the contents back in, you simply need to do something like...

```
try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
    users = (ArrayList<User>) is.readObject();
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now, because the `JTextArea` now needs to be updated in two places, I created a simple method...

```
protected void updateList() {
    for (User object : users) {
        S.append(object + "\n");
    }
    String text = S.toString();
    data.setText(text);
}
```

Which simply updates the `JTextArea` with the current contents of the `User` list.

This I added to the load code...

```
try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
    users = (ArrayList<User>) is.readObject();
    updateList();
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which I placed at the end of your classes constructor (so that the UI was initialised first)

As Braj  keeps mentioning, this code comes from your `actionPerformed` method (after the two `if` statements), which means it really is in the wrong place.  The only time you want to execute this code is when the list has changed, for example...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == submitButton) {
        name = realname.getText();
        uname = username.getText();
        getPassword();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(users.get(i).toString());
        }
        updateList();
    } else if (source == quitButton) {
        try (ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("userfile.txt"))) {
            os.writeObject(users);
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now, having said all that, Object serialization is NOT a good choice for the long term storage of data, serialization was meant for the short term storage of Objects, typically for transmission across the wire (but not limited to).

For structured data, I prefer to use XML, Java has a nice XML bindings, see [Introduction to JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) for more details.

This isn't the only option, check out [How can I save the state of my program and then load it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for a more detail description.

Comment: and any code after `System.exit(0);` should not be there?

Comment: @Braj It's in a `if-else` statement, technically, you could execute code in other branches for other reasons...

Comment: yes that's why I am pointing this thing. There is some code after `if` condition.

Comment: @Braj Yep, but the question is, what does it do, it updates the `JTextArea`, which technically means, it doesn't belong there...

Comment: So i added what you told me to but im not sure if i added them in the right place because it is still not saving any additional users. It only saved the first user i put in on the first run. I edited my question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is not writing something!

In your code:

```
if (source == quitButton) {
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream("userfile.txt");
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ev) {
                ev.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Your just read something and do nothing with your fis ,right?

Comment: Actually, if you look at the start of the `actionPerformed`, the OP actually DID write the contents of the file, but for some reason I don't know, read the file on quit, instead of reading it when the class was constructed...