# Using the 'value of' method and trying to store data fails in Java, why?

Tags: java

I have a program I'm writing. I want the program to be able to stop, and start off where it left off the next time I run it. I have some int variables. The way I'm storing the data only works in Strings, so I have been trying to do this with my integer variables:

```
attack = Integer.valueOf(wordAttack);
```

Here is the way I'm trying to get the information:

```
wordAttack = (prop1.getProperty("dbattack"));
```

Here is how I'm trying storing the data:

```
String wordAttack = String.valueOf(attack);
```

and

```
prop.setProperty("dbattack", wordAttack);
```

If there is a way to store the value of an int similar to the way I am know, please let me know. I would really like to know how I can store these integers for the next time I run the programs.
     Thanks,
    ~Rane

Comment: Learn how to write to a file. There are more sophisticated ways to do it, but for now I would start with FileWriter. Here's a link with some information. http://www.journaldev.com/878/how-to-write-a-file-in-java-using-filewriter-bufferedwriter-files-and-fileoutputstream

Comment: Take a look at [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for a discussion on some available persistance mechanisms for data

Comment: Assuming that `prop` is a `Properties` class, you can use `Properties#store` to write the contents to a file...

Comment: "Here is the way I'm trying to get the information" -- And does it work? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing something big I would suggest you to learn how to use a database.

If you are doing something smaller you can write your own files. Also there is a way to serializa a Java object and save it but if you change the object after then you will lose what you already have.