# How do I save a user's printer choice in Java application (NetBeans)?

Tags: java, netbeans, printing

I will be using NetBeans to create my application. What I need to know is this...

If I add a printer setup menu, which will be used to display a print dialog and allow the user to select a specific printer for a specific option (ex: one printer for receipts, one printer for reports, etc. (and the user can select the same printer for all options, if desired)), how can I save the user's printer choice and access that later?

For example, I might choose to print a receipt when the user finishes entering a transaction and clicks "Save". The printer that the document is sent to should be the printer that is chosen in the printer set up menu. How can I design my application in a way that will allow this?

As always, thank you in advance for any helpful answers.

Comment: Look into the Preferences class (java.util.prefs).

Comment: Take look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for discussion on possible solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to persist a choice of printer over multiple sessions, I would recommend storing the information as a table in a database. Each choice of printer for a given 'option' (probably a more descriptive term should be chosen) is saved as a line in the database, for example User: (foreign key to user table), Purpose: (foreign key to table of purposes), Printer: (address of the printer to be used?), optionally PrinterName for display purposes.

Comment: This seems like a perfect solution. I could just store the address (basically location) of the printer. But how would I call that in my program?

For example, let's say I want to print a panel. When I use the print() functionality, where would I enter the code, and what would I enter?

Comment: I figured out a workaround. First, I generated a ComboBox with the printer choices for the user. Then, I set the print service index (from an array of PrintServices) to the same index as that which is selected in the ComboBox (since the ComboBox will have the same choices, in the same order, as the print services array). This allowed me to print to any printer I chose without having to display a print dialog first, which is exactly what I wanted. Basically, if the user types information in and clicks "Save", I want a document to be printed immediately, without a dialog every time.