# How to save state of a JFrame java 1.6

Tags: java, jframe, save

How would I make it so when my frame is closed it saves itself, and if started again it continues from where it was last. I am coding in Java 1.6 on eclipse

Comment: Take a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to save the state of a window and all of it's components. You have to do it manually. Usually this is done with config files. When the frame closes, you store all of it's components values in a file, and when the frame opens it reads that file and reloads the component's values. Take a look at Properties, something perfectly fit for that need.
here is a good tutorial to start with:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/