# Saving and Recalling data on java

Tags: java, file-upload

Im new to programming, and I am making a code in which I record boolean data each day of the week to see if the user did the task that they are required to do.

For example:

Press 'y' if you went to soccer practice today.

Press 'n' if you didn't.

I need the program to be able to ask this for all five days of the week and in the end record the number of times they went to soccer practice in one month. I have the basic idea on how to make the code for something if the user was going to enter it in one opening. But I need to save that boolean data every single day, and then recall... any ideass.....thankx

Comment: You'll need a loop of some kind. You can look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) zero a discussion on different persistence approches

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the values to some persistent storage. The simplest is file. Other could be database. So you need to find out how to read/write from

Answer (score 0):

Java allows you to create file objects and read and write to them which is what you need. Here is a basic example to help you get started:

```
import java.io.*

public class MyFileReaderWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File myFile = new File("sample.txt");
        try {
            BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile));
            w.write(Integer.toString(1));
            w.write(Integer.toString(0));
            w.write("HELLO WORLD");

            w.close();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
            String s = r.readLine();

            System.out.println(s);

            r.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of a static Map (collection) which will gets created only at the start of the program and add the data to the map at the end of each day.