# What is the best practice to store configuration settings in a desktop application?

Tags: java, swing, configuration, desktop-application

I have a desktop swing application. There is certain configuration data which I need throughout the application. I load the config. from database on application loading and currently keep the same in a public static final Map. What would be the better alternate approach?

Comment: I'd prefer a Singleton over a `static` `HashMap` or maybe the `Preferences` API instead.  Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) discussion for more details

Comment: I saw your post. Singleton looks good to me as Preferences API will not provide me the handle to change the preferences value once loaded. Correct me if I am wrong. I should be able to change the value of any preference. I chose Map as its the same way we have ThreadLocal objects in a web based application.

Comment: `Preferences` is a storage mechanism, if your persist the values through the API, they will change. But since you seem to already have persistence taken care of, it might not be entirely suitable.  The singleton would allow you to define and control access

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, one of the way is using a [property file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) ( key-value style)

Comment: The configuration is in DB and also it can be an object.

Comment: If you are trying to save objects you may want to look into serializing/deserializing objects and write them into file(s) so that you can load them again afterwards. If you have many objects you can try a combination of both: properties files and objects you are caching in files - hope that helps

Comment: This is bug bear for me, but object serializing/deserializing for the purpose of long term storage is a bad idea, it was simply never designed for this.  The OP already has a persistence layer, the database, they just need away to access it from within the application