# User Input in a Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, user-input

I have been recently trying to figure out what I should use to get user input in a GUI. I want the user to input text into the GUI and have the program save the text so I can use it later. I already have a basic understanding of programming GUI's. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Which framework? Swing, SWT, GWT, JavaFX...?

Comment: You might want to look at [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html), [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: And [for persistence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JTextField` or `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`. Is your question is how can you get the input value from this Swing? Or just asking what you can use?

Comment: My question is: what do I use? A description of how to use it is optional but helpful.

Comment: @Jluponeage `JTextField` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you work your way through the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), specifically the section on [text widgets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).