# Add row in JTable one by one in different JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to add row in a JTable consistently. I have two Frames. From the first frame I will take data like below-

[image: myFrame.java]
(Frame 1)

And in the second frame I have made a JTable like-

[image: List.java]
(Frame 2)

I have added an actionListener in the first frame's "Submit" button like-

```
private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    int a = 1, room = 301;
    List li = new List();

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) List.table.getModel();
    model.addRow(new Object[]{a++,name.getText(),mobile.getText(),ward.getText(),room++});

    li.setVisible(true);

}
```

I could add a row successfully. But, the problem is when I add another Patient detail, It adds that data in a different frame and previous data vanishes itself. I don't know the cause as I doing this for the first time.
I want to show this in list frame consistently.

**I have tried to do this in the same frame, if I input data and click OK, It can add the row one by one, I searched in youtube and found this to do this in only one frame, when I want to do so in two separate frame, it don't add rows. It repaces the previous row only.**

Comment: Pass a reference of the `TableModel` to the second class, fill as desired;  Use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to get notifications from the "generator" class for when things have been "generated", fill table as desired; Use a [Producer/Consumer Pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern), fill as desired; Use a dialog, fill in the details, when closed, as the dialog for the details and fill table as desired, see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

Comment: As I am new to this, will you please explain more? Or, can you give a link to learn this process?

Comment: There are three links in the previous comment, I recommend the last one

Comment: Is there any way to store previous data that I added to table even if I close the frame window?

Comment: For a discussions on your options, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052)

Answer (score 0):

Simply because you created the JFrame object "Li" inside the ActionListener function so each time you click the button it creates a new frame, try creating the JFrame Object outside the function it should work