# Storing User Data Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

So, I am making a program on Java Swing that has a login and create player area. The thing is, I'm stuck on how to save the data (username and password) introduced by the user when creating a player. Basically, the data will be later used to validate the user's login. I've been suggested to use an array of strings; but I'm a beginner and I've read several pages and looked up video tutorials and have no idea how to save such data. I would really appreciate some help; and please excuse any grammar mistakes, I'm not a native english speaker haha..

Comment: If you are wanting the program to save data even after it is terminated, you will have to save it in a database.

Comment: Or `java.util.prefs.Preferences`.

Comment: There are any number of possibilities, have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your purposes as a beginner, you probably will not want to get into any database or encryption code and stick with simple file I/O. Basically, you programatically create a new file and you write all the data to it.

```
try {
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("mydata.ser");

    writer.println(getUserName());
    writer.println(getPassword());

    writer.close();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

...

try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mydata.ser"));

    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());

    reader.close();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

What you do here is you create a new file with a PrintWriter and write to it the username and password. That way, after your program ends, the data still exists in the file. Then when you want to load the data again, you chain a BufferedReader to a FileReader and read lines from the file. Notice I close both the PrintWriter and the BufferedReader.

Because you are a beginner, I realize you may not know what try-catch is (if you do, I'm sorry for assuming you didn't but I just want to be safe). You *try* to execute the code in the block, but if an exception occurs of the type specified in the catch block (in this case, Exception or any of its subclasses; aka any exception), then the program will skip over to the catch block and in this case, it will print the stack trace of the error. An error may occur while handling files if you cannot write/read to it for some reason or (for some objects) if the file does not exist.

I hope this helps.