# Storing an array so that I can access it the next time I run the program

Tags: java

I have this array

```
String[][] someArrayOfData={{"there","is"},{"alot","of data here"}};
```

I want to be able to save this array so I can load and access it the next time I run the program.
I dont mind having to use just a `String[]` as well. I have tried to write it to a notepad file but that is just a major irritation, is it possible to store variables externally to avoid the hassle of writing to multiple notepad files or using delineators?

Comment: If you want to 'save' some data then you have to use either files or database.

Comment: Think about this from a technical standpoint. Where can you save data on a computer. Well you can mostly write it to memory, which is temporary, or the hard drive (through many different channels) which is permanent.

Comment: Database is your friend.

Comment: Use any database to save the data and then access the data from database whenever the program starts running

Comment: Persistence takes many forms, have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for more details and options

Comment: You have to persist somewhere. Can go for the serialization, but since it is just strings, plain ascii file should suffice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple possibilities. In all cases this is called persistence.

1. Store to file
   [Store to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java)
2. Store to database
   [Java DB tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)
3. Send it somewhere
   [Simple REST web service and client](http://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/)

In principle 3 is not persistence, but it is a way to get the data out of the volatile memory.

Comment: Could you please reply with code or a link that can tell me how to do such a thing. How do I create a database. I am trying to avoid using notepad

Comment: thanks just saw the links pop up

Comment: Question says *nothing* about Android, so why are two of your choices Android based?

Comment: right, correcting, thanks