# How to save the last selected folder after closing application?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, awt, application-settings

Could you tell me, how to save the last selected folder in java swing app, so that the next time, when I activate my app it automatically loaded?

I am writing an application that reads images and forming slideshow. I have everything but that record the selected folder?

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out `Properties` in java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html. Can save the state to properties and read it in again the next time.

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for some ideas.  In this case, I tend to prefer using the `Preferences` API for it's simplicty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas?

There are many possible approaches, but here are a couple of straight-forward ones:

- Record the application state that you want to persist in a [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object.  As the application exits, use one of the save / store methods to save the properties to a file.  When the application is restarted, load the state from the file ... if it exists.
- Read up on the [Java Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/prefs/package-summary.html) APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way for you is the `Preferences` class, and basically works this way:

```
//You can get the stored path and for the case there isn´t any you set the default path
Preferences lastdir = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(Main.class);
String dirStr = lastdir.get("lastdir","c:/default");

//Then you store the new value each time you change the path
lastdir.put("lastdir","c:/new dir");//Stores the new value
```