# How to save Image inside the Java project

Tags: java, swing

The picture here is where the picture will be set.

```
    private void btnOpenPic1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
    { 
        int pic1 = jFileChooser1.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (pic1 == jFileChooser1.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            File f = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
            btnPic1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(""+ f));
            btnPic1.setText("");
         }
    }
```

now after setting the picture. How will i be able to save that picture into the project java so that next time it loads, it will still appear there.

```
private void btnSavePic1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                            

}
```

Comment: You could use `jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile()` and [copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) the file to the location you want (beware though, under systems like Windows and MacOS, they get picky about where you can write stuff to).  You could simply save a "reference" to the image (from `jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile()`) and save the path/name information in a text/properties file

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you be more elaborate like citing an example. I'm new to java programming.
BTW I'm using Windows.

Comment: Some persistence [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052), [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html), [Properties trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)