# GUI for settings with save capabilities via Hashmap of Objects (java)

Tags: java, user-interface, hashmap, save, settings

I am having trouble creating a GUI that will save my settings into a text file. This is what I have implemented so far.

```
    private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 760, 494);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel lblMudknife = new JLabel("MudKnife");
    lblMudknife.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
    panel.add(lblMudknife);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane.addTab("Build", null, panel_1, null);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);

    JTabbedPane tabbedPane_1 = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Settings", null, tabbedPane_1, null);

    JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane_1.addTab("Environment", null, panel_2, null);
    panel_2.setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
    tabbedPane_1.addTab("Scraper", null, panel_3, null);    
    panel_3.setLayout(null);
```

....

```
    HashMap<String, Object[]> hm = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
    Object[] a = new Object[2];
```

...

```
    a[0] = new JLabel("SecondFactorHREF");
    a[1] = new JTextField();
    hm.put("SecondFactorHREF", a);

    a[0] = new JLabel("SplashPage");
    a[1] = new JTextField();
    hm.put("SplashPage", a);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    int widthLabel = 70;
    int heightLabel = 15;
    int widthField = 90;
    int heightField = 15;

    for (Entry<String, Object[]> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
        key = entry.getKey();
        label =  (JLabel) entry.getValue()[0];
        label.setText(key);
        label.setBounds(x, y, widthLabel, heightLabel);
        field = (JTextField) entry.getValue()[1];
        field.setBounds(x+90,y,widthField,heightField);
        panel_2.add(label);
        panel_2.add(field);
        System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString());
        System.out.println("Key, Label Value, Field Value: " + key + ", " + label.getName() + ", " + field.getText());
        y += 15;
    }
```

This will no show correctly in the layout. It seems to only show the last one that is in the hashMap.

From here I have a class that will save any object to a file. Then I plan on just reading the object and iterating through it when I need to initialize the settings.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-to-save-the-state-of-my-minesweeper-game-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for more ideas about how you might save the state of your UI

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: I'd then having a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and  [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for an alternative to what you're currently trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep adding the same array object to your HashMap, but while you continually change its contents, it's still the same exact array object, and the array reference never changes. If you want to add a new array object, you should create a new array object.

Better still, simply make it a `HashMap<String, JTextField>` and create the JLabel on the fly:

```
HashMap<String, JTextField> hm = new HashMap<>();

// ........

hm.put("SecondFactorHREF", new JTextField());
hm.put("SplashPage", new JTextField());

for (Entry<String, JTextField> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
    key = entry.getKey();
    label =  new JLabel(key);
    // .... no done't set bounds -- use layout managers!
    // label.setBounds(x, y, widthLabel, heightLabel);
    field = entry.getValue();
    // field.setBounds(x+90,y,widthField,heightField);  // again use layout managers
    panel_2.add(label);
    panel_2.add(field);
}
```

Also, don't use null layouts and setBounds but rather use layout managers. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

Comment: And consider having a look at [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and  [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for an alternative to what you're currently trying ;)