# Hello, I want to create a javafx project, but does it need Database?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I want to create a javafx project, but does it need Database?

when I create this program save these name when I input this name and other. I mean save the result in the program and show me when I run it, I don’t need to be store for along time .just for that time when I will run it?

Comment: No. Creating a JavaFX app does not require you to set up a database.

Comment: you only need a database if you need to store data in between program runs. If it is small data you can even simply store it in a File.

Comment: There's lots of different ways you "might" does this, which you might use depends on your needs - maybe have a look at [How can I save the state of my program and then load it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556932/how-can-i-save-the-state-of-my-program-and-then-load-it/19557052#19557052) for more details

Comment: Thanks @DevashishJaiswal

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no, JavaFX can run without database and you don't need to use it.

If you need to sava data that only while program is running but don't need to save it for next use of program then you can simply use some `Collection` or custom data structure to hold what you need in `runtime`, but bare in mind that this means that all data will reset once you quit program.

If you need to save data even when program shuts down then you will need to use some kind of database, if you want to save a small amount of data then you can use `json`, `xml` or even raw `txt` files, for more data you should take look at some `SQL/NoSQL` database.